# Ao injetar uma dependência na controller, Postman retorna erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Ao fazer isso no meu `Controller`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OptOutClientController : Controller
    {
        IOptOutService _service;

        //Se comentar o construtor dá certo
        public OptOutClientController(IOptOutService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<OptOutResult> Unsubscribe([FromBody]OptOutCliente cliente)
        {
            if (cliente == null)
                throw new OptOutException("Informar os dados do cliente OptOut!");

            var result = await _service.Process(new OptOutCliente(cliente.Cpf, cliente.Email, cliente.Telefone, cliente.Bandeira, cliente.Canal));

            return null;

        }

    }
```

Eu recebo um `Internal Server Error (500)` com a injeção no construtor. Se comento o construtor, então funciona. O que devo passar no Postman ou na chamada do serviço para não receber esse erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1**

Minha `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddMvc();
         services.AddRouting();
     }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
     {
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "optoutroute",
                    template: "{controller=OptOutClient}/{action=Index}");
            });
     }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Minha Startup ficou assim o métodoConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddRouting();
            services.AddScoped<IOptOutService, ClientUnsubscribe>();
        }
```

Minha controller está assim

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private readonly IOptOutService _service;
        public OptOutClientController(IOptOutService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
..........
```

Na startup tentei: Scoped, Singleton, Transient, todos os ciclos e continua com Server Error

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, como eu faria isso? Em qual método do Startup eu faria isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1 e aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa declarar essa dependência de IOptOutService, no método ConfigureServices da classe Startup.

```
services.addScoped<IOptOutService, SuaImplementacao>();
```

Comment: No méodo eu troquei de FromBody para FromServices e nada ainda

Comment: O erro estava na classe que implementa a interface.